# gem_original_require: no such file to load -- spec/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rspec

I have a rails 2.3.8 app with rspec tests (not written by me, just trying to get them running).  When I run "rake spec" I get this error:

```
gem_original_require': no such file to load -- spec/rails (MissingSourceFile)
```

I have the following rspec-related gems installed:

```
rails (2.3.8, 2.3.5)
rspec (2.0.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.9, 1.2.4)
rspec-core (2.0.1)
rspec-expectations (2.0.1)
rspec-mocks (2.0.1)
rspec-rails (2.0.1)
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?  Interestingly, if I drop my rails version to 2.3.5 (in environment.rb) I get a completely different error:

```
Missing the Rails 2.3.5 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.5 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
```

Not sure if the two are related.  I have both rails versions installed because this machine runs a few different rails apps (for continuous integration).  I suspect I'm just in gem version hell, but I'm unsure how to get out of it.

Any advice appreciated,
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have rspec 2 install or it's not compatible to Rails 2.3.x. So uninstall it and use only Rspec 1.3 You can use Bundler if you want sandbox your gem by project or rvm with a gemset.

```
gem uninstall rspec -v=2.0.1
```